# Ошибка при чтении XML файла

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте хочу вывести в консоль атрибут из xml файла

```
try {
    XDocument doc = new XDocument.Load(@ "Pay.xml");
    doc.Load();
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("response/auth/payment");
    foreach(XmlNode n in nodes)
        result = n.SelectSingleNode("@resultCode").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
} 

catch (XmlException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Объявление XML должно быть первым узлом в документе, использование
>   знаков пробела перед ним не допускается.

Как исправить?

Вот XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <requestNum>525</requestNum>
  <terminalNum>742</terminalNum>
  <auth>
    <payment trn="0000000002"  resultCode="215" timeget="2020-01-10 17:05:19" />
  </auth>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у вас не совсем верный XML с точки зрения библиотеки и стандарта. Нужен корневой элемент, который содержит остальные как узлы.

source.xml (обратите внимание, что файл должен находится там же где и exe файл прогаммы.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<responses>
<response>
  <requestNum>525</requestNum>
  <terminalNum>742</terminalNum>
  <auth>
    <payment trn="0000000002"  resultCode="215" timeget="2020-01-10 17:05:19" />
  </auth>
</response>
  <response>
    <requestNum>52</requestNum>
    <terminalNum>74</terminalNum>
    <auth>
      <payment trn="0000000001"  resultCode="215" timeget="2020-01-10 17:05:19" />
    </auth>
  </response>


</responses>
```

Далее пример чтения данных

```
 try
            {

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("source.xml");

                foreach (XElement element in doc.Element("responses").Elements("response"))
                {

                    XElement requestNum = element.Element("requestNum");
                    XElement terminalNum = element.Element("terminalNum");
                    XElement auth = element.Element("auth").Element("payment");
                    Console.WriteLine("Num={0}: term={1}, auth={2}", requestNum.Value, terminalNum.Value, auth.Attribute("trn").Value);


                }
            }

            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```